# get root permission of iOS

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to get the root permision of iOS??

As I know it is not possible. But to confirm can it be done by jailbroking the device.
I need to do some system call also get the buffer frame root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get root permission on your device, only by jail breaking it.

Comment: thanks, Can you also please let me know how to to get the root permission? or after jailbroking the device wil it be by default